# What is the source of inspiration for the Fat Bastard character?

Tags: character, austin-powers

I've been trying to find an interview with Mike Myers where he supposedly mentions the inspiration for the Fat Bastard character. My friend swears that Mike Myers said he saw an obese guy in Nashville, TN playing the bagpipes and that was where he got the idea for Fat Bastard. So who is the inspirational character for Fat Bastard?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find any mention of any interview with Mike Myers where he reveals the inspiration for *Fat Bastard*. That does not mean that there was none. But I'd like to venture that if such a revelation had ever been made, then it would have been mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Bastard_%28character%29), [here](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0028712/bio), [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FatBastard), or [here](http://austinpowers.wikia.com/wiki/Fat_Bastard).

My first impression when I saw *Fat Bastard* (and this opinion is shared in a number of [locations](http://www.imdb.com/reviews/188/18818.html)) was that he was modelled on the legendary character of [Mr. Creosote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Creosote) from [Monty Python's The Meaning of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python%27s). Myers grew up with [Monty Python](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2010/jul/03/mike-myers-family-values) and would have undoubtedly encountered the double Jeroboam swilling Creosote.

> Dad loved movies and I grew up with British comedy. My ultimate favourite is Peter Sellers. I loved the Ealing comedies, **Monty Python**, Alec Guinness. It's true that Englishness, comedy and otherwise, is a very big part of my life: and there's nobody more English than an Englishman who no longer lives in England.

[image]

Comment: I always considered him to be a combination of Creosote as well as Oddjob. The latter being the classic "henchman" as well as being foreign. They just changed him from Asian to Scottish to make him more "British".

Comment: @Mario but you had Random Task as the direct parallel to Odd Job in the previous movie. I wouldnt have thought they would try to do another, less obvious version immediately after,

Answer (score 0):

The late Kenny Ireland was a director and actor on Scottish Theater and many British TV shows. He was a guest actor in shows such as Midsomer Murders, New Tricks, and Monarch of the Glen and many others.  I immediately thought of Fat Bastard after watching Season 2 of New Tricks where he plays a bookie, named George Moore. This is made with an assumption that growing up in Canada Mike Myers may have saw one of his guest or starring shots.

Answer (score -1):

There was a character in the book, Ozma of Oz named Hungry Tiger.
He would exclaim that he wanted to eat a fat baby, while being disgusted with himself about it.
Fat Bastard might be a hybrid of a few different muzes.

Answer (score -6):

That obese piper was me and I am Fat bastard. My name is Matthew and I was known at one time in Nashville as "Bagpipe Guy" I was the hardest working gig bagpiper in the state, maybe in the country. I averaged about 20 funerals a month, 2 weddings and a host of fire fighter, marine and Police gigs. I also played on the street corner near Mr. Myers's restaurant haunt and i weighed about 525 pounds at the time. The story goes that he was trying to have a chat with someone as I was playing, and every time he would speak, i would play a high and loud note. he then allegedly said "damn, would someone please shut that fat bastard down!!?" Thus Fat bastard was born.